# How, if possible, to add "Archive to a storage account" in terraform?

Tags: azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

Is there an option to enable "Archive to a storage account" in Keyvault diagnostic in Azure provider of Terraform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to configure diagnostic settings for Azure  Key Vault, we can [use the `azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/monitor_diagnostic_setting.html) to configure it. For more details, please refer to [here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/3456#issuecomment-493402206)

For example

1. Create a service principal

```
az login
az account set --subscription "SUBSCRIPTION_ID"
az ad sp create-for-rbac --role "Contributor" --scopes "/subscriptions/<subscription_id>"
```

2. Script

```
provider "azurerm" {

    version = "~>2.0"
        subscription_id = ""
        client_id = "sp appId"
        client_secret = "sp password"
        tenant_id = "sp tenant"
        features {}

}

data "azurerm_storage_account" "mystorage" {
    name = ""
    resource_group_name = ""
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "mykey" {
    name = ""
    resource_group_name =""
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "example" {
  name               = "example"
  target_resource_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.mykey.id
  storage_account_id = data.azurerm_storage_account.mystorage.id

  log {
    category = "AuditEvent"
    enabled  = false

    retention_policy {
      enabled = false
    }
  }

  metric {
    category = "AllMetrics"

    retention_policy {
      enabled = false
    }
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't see how it solves Archive to a storage account object.

Comment: @OmerShliva After doing that, Azure will send logs to the Azure storage account : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/diagnostic-settings#create-using-azure-cli